# Issues creating Json schema with enums

Tags: json, jsonschema

I am new to JSON and I am trying to create a JSON schema for a JSON object. There are tools online that can easily create JSON schema from a JSON object but my JSON seems to be complicated and needs some tweaking, but I am not sure how

example json

```
{
    "iD": 123456789,
    "balance": {
      "currency": "Pounds",
      "balance": 260.25,
      "date": "2022-03-03"
    },
    "Permissions": {
      "granted": [
          "canLoginWithPassword",
          "canGame",
          "canWithdraw"
      ],
      "failedConditions": [
        {
          "name": "we move",
          "description": "Deposit Block",
          "details": {
            "reason": "Deposit Block"
          },
          "denied": [
            "canDeposit"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

The problem I am having is not being able to represent the `granted` section and `denied` section with enumerations. The `granted` and `denied` sections can have one or all of the privileges

Privileges

```
          "canLoginWithPassword",
          "canGame",
          "canWithdraw", 
          "canDeposit"
```

Comment: You should always consider JSON Schema generated from JSON data to be a scaffold only. You cannot expect a tool to guess correctly all the things you want.

Answer (score 0):

From reading your question, I think the `items`, `uniqueItems` and `enum` keywords are the way to go for your schema:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
  "description": "JSON schema generated with JSONBuddy https://www.json-buddy.com",
  "properties": {
    "Permissions": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/Permissions"
    },
    "balance": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/balance"
    },
    "iD": {
      "type": "integer"
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "privileges": {
      "type": "array",
      "uniqueItems": true,
      "items": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
          "canLoginWithPassword",
          "canGame",
          "canWithdraw",
          "canDeposit"
        ]
      }
    },  
    "details": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "reason": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "Permissions": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "failedConditions": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "denied": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/privileges"
              },
              "description": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "details": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/details"
              },
              "name": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "granted": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/privileges"
        }
      }
    },
    "balance": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "balance": {
          "type": "number"
        },
        "currency": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "date": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks alot @Clemens. If you run the schema on https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-schema-to-json-converter the permission appear as empty array

Comment: True. It seems the data generation does not support the enumeration. Using JSONBuddy, the granted and denied keys are filled in the generated sample data.

Comment: Using uniqueItems : true and minItems: 2 seems to work but it only produces 1 item instead of 2

Comment: As @relequestal said, don't rely on sample data and schema generation. There are always shortcomings included.