# Issues using MinItem and uniqueItem: true to generate multiple enums

Tags: json, jsonschema

I am trying to create a JSON schema that validates a JSON object which can have more than 1 enum.
I have successfully created a JSON schema that is expected to validate a JSON object but the problem I am having is ensuring that the schema accepts more than one enum.

when I use the `minItem : 3`, three enums are generated but they are duplicates. when I add `uniqueItem: true` it only returns 1 enum instead of 3 unique enums.

My json schem:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "$id": "https://mrlee.com/player.schema.json",
    "title": "The lee schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "AccountID":{
            "description": "The unique identifier for a user", 
            "type": "integer" 
        },
        "Permissions":{
            "type": "object",
            "properties":{
                "granted":{
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "type":"string",
                        "enum":[
                            "canLoginWithPassword",
                            "canVerify",
                            "canGame",
                            "canJump"
                        ]
                    },
                    "minItems" : 4,
                    "uniqueItems": true
                },
                "failedConditions":{ 
                    "type": "array",
                    "items":[
                        {"type":"object",
                            "properties":{
                                "name":{
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "description":{
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "details":{
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties":{
                                        "reason":{
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "required": [ "reason"]
                                },
                                "denied":{
                                    "type": "array",
                                    "items":{
                                        "type":"string",
                                        "enum":[
                                            "canLoginWithPassword",
                                            "canLoginWithPassword",
                                            "canVerify",
                                            "canGame",
                                            "canJump"
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "minItems":1,
                                   "maxItems": 5
                                }  
                            },
                            "required": [ "name", "description", "details","denied" ]   }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "required": [ "granted", "failedConditions" ]
        } 
    },
    "required": [ "AccountID", "Permissions"]
```

to test that my json schema works, I use this [link](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-schema-to-json-converter). would be glad if im pointed in the right direction as I am new to json and json schema

Comment: Even if the sample data generation from the link does not produce all of the content you expect, it does not mean your schema is not correct or suitable. The sample data generator produces JSON according to its name, just as samples. Only you know what your real data will look like and you have to test your schema against your input JSON. Don't use a sample data generator to "test" your schema.

Comment: JSON data generation is tricky. You might try my generator at json-everything.net. iIt's algorithm a bit more complex than some others I've found.  It does have a few limitations, like it can't do `$ref`s, but it should be able to handle the above.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71677436/issues-creating-json-schema-with-enums. And you're not showing what data you expect to be validated that isn't working with your schema, so it's really hard to guess what your problem is.